# Problem filtering data dynamically in Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery

I am working with version 3 of Fullcalendar, so far everything works, except when I want to filter the data to be displayed according to the criteria of applied flitro:
Based on the value of a combobox, I try to filter the data to be displayed by a specific field in the calendar.
This code works perfect for me:

```
events:'php/eventos.php',

  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) 
  {
      // event.id_tratamiento
      return ['all', event.id_tratamiento].indexOf($('#data_selector').val()) >= 0
  },

  // función combobox filtro :
  $('#data_selector').on('change', function() 
  {
      if (this.value) 
      {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      }
   }
```

But if I want to dynamically change the field to be filtered, it doesn't work for me:

```
  if(condicion==1)
  {
    campo=event.id_tratamiento;
  }
  elseif (condicion==2)
  { 
    campo=event.id_profesional;
  }
  else
  {                           
    campo=event.id_tipo;
  }                    

  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) 
  {                  
      // event.id_tratamiento
      return ['all', campo].indexOf($('#data_selector').val()) >= 0
  }
```

or

```
  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) 
  {                  
      // event.id_tratamiento
      return ['all', 'id_'+campo].indexOf($('#data_selector').val()) >= 0
  }
```

It doesn't show me any error messages, and in the Chrome debug screen it doesn't show anything abnormal either, but it doesn't filter anything, the calendar is blank
Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best option is show all events and add a custom class to every category, with this custom class you can hide and show events via jquery

```
var event={
    ...
    className: 'category_'+idCategory,
};
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, true);
```

Then, when your select is changed you show the right category with jquery

```
$('#data_selector').on('change', function() {     
    $('.fc-event').hide();
    $('.category_'+this.value).show();
}
```